# how to display google map using vuejs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

How to display google map using  vue js? I have given code below. It's giving **maps is undefined** but I have installed all dependencies for that google map.

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```

below is my script

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {}
  },
  mounted() {
    let myLatlng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946);
    let mapOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: myLatlng,
      scrollwheel: true,
    };
    let map = new window.google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById("map"),
      mapOptions
    );

    let marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      title: "Banglore"
    });
```

Comment: so, `window.google` is OK, but `window.google.maps` is undefined?

Comment: "maps is undefined" or "Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined"?

Answer (score 0):

[vue2-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps) exposes components you can use for the map and markers

```
<template>
    <GmapMap
        :center="center"
        :zoom="14"
    >
        <GmapMarker
            :position="markerPosition"
        />
    </GmapMap>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            center: {
                lat: 12.9716,
                lng: 77.5946
            },
            markerPosition: {
                lat: 12.9716,
                lng: 77.5946
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

---

If you need access to the google object, vue2-google-maps recommends making a computed property.

```
<script>
import {gmapApi} from 'vue2-google-maps'

export default {
    computed: {
        google: gmapApi
    }
}
</script>
```